# How to Encrypt after creating TAR Archive

Tags: bash, shell

How to Encrypt TAR File with password.

Trying to compare TAR archive content with file system however we are encrypting TAR. Would like to --compare TAR file first then encrypt.

```
# tar -cvf compare1.tar compare/*
# tar --compare --file=compare1.tar compare/*

# tar --compare --file=compare1.tar compare/*
tar: compare/test: Not found in archive
```

Encrypted TAR File

```
# tar --compare --file=ArchiveVerify.tar compare
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: compare: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 17):

To encrypt tar file with password you need to use gpg.

encrypt:

```
tar czvpf - file1.txt file2.pdf file3.jpg \
 | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 -o myarchive.tar.gz
```

decrypt:

```
gpg -d myarchive.tar.gz.gpg | tar xzvf -
```

For more information you can see:

https://www.putorius.net/how-to-create-enrcypted-password.html

Comment: What is the role of the '-' after czvpf in the first command ?

Comment: In this case, the '-' in tar command goes together with the -f option. You can find the explanation in: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_45.html "If you use '-' as an archive-name, tar reads the archive from standard input (when listing or extracting files), or writes it to standard output (when creating an archive). If you use '-' as an archive-name when modifying an archive, tar reads the original archive from its standard input and writes the entire new archive to its standard output."

Comment: Be warned that you still need to export your encryption key or you won't be able to decrypt it later!

Comment: No need for the `p` option in `tar`. It only has an effect for extraction.

Comment: Note: This method prompts you for a passphrase both when encrypting and decrypting, and is thus not automateable as-is.

Answer (score 13):

To encrypt a tar with a password you also can use openssl.

Encrypt:

```
tar -cO a/ | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc  -md md5 -pass pass:mypassword > a.bin
```

Decrypt:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc  -md md5 -pass pass:mypassword -in a.bin  | tar -x
```

If you want to store a password in a file, use the command below. You should change `-pass pass:derp` into `-pass file:my.key` in the commands above.

```
openssl rand -out my.key 128
```

Comment: Please stop using md5 for keys. The default is currently sha-256 so you can just remove `-md md5` in both encrypt and decrypt commands. Reference: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/enc.1ssl.html

Comment: @Keehl Agreed, but OP should add `-md` for sha256 since the default can change over the years.

Comment: One day sha256 will be considered insecure just like md5 is today, then the default will change and that is a good thing. This post and comment will probably outlast sha256. I think it's a good idea to be aware of which algorithm is being used.

Comment: Indeed, I have faced just this, with legacy backup infrastructure… then trying to migrate to newer hosts. `openssl` will gladly "decrypt" a file with the wrong digest, only to output garbage.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `age` (for instance with Mozilla Sops which require the key to be put in `$HOME/.config/sops/age/keys.txt`) then, you can encrypt the tar.gz file like this:

```
age -r public-key -a myarchive.tar.gz > myarchive.tar.gz.age
```

The public-key is displayed by age when the keypair is generated, and is present as a comment in the keys.txt file.

It can then be decrypted like this:

```
age -d -i ~/.config/sops/age/keys.txt < myarchive.tar.gz.age | tar tvf
```